# Python: Find black background in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image and I would like to find the intensity of zero region (black). My idea is to draw a small box around the black region. This is what I expect as an outcome.

[image]
`(x, y)` is the center of the box. I draw `40` unit box around it

My attempt is as follow;

```
import cv2
from random import *

img = cv2.imread("path/to/image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 800)) 
rows,cols = img.shape[:2]

try:
    for i in range(100):
        x = randint(1, rows)    # Pick a random number between 1 and rows.
        y = randint(1, cols)    # Pick a random number between 1 and rows.

        while True:
            sum_intensity = 0
            for i in range(x-20, x+20):
                for j in range(y-20, y+20):
                    intensity = img[i,j]
                    sum_intensity += intensity

            if sum_intensity == 0:
                print("zero intensity found")
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x-20, y+20), (x+20, y-20), (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.imwrite("path/to/save.png", img) 
                break

            else:
                print("No zero intensity")
                break

except:
    pass
```

one example of the generated boxes are as below.. you can see in which there are overlapping boxes with the gray region, which I want to avoid!! I have to pick the complete background (black). Also I just need a one box... no need to see several of them. I know I can use a boolian variable, but dont know how in python. 
[image]

Comment: Always think to provide the original images, free of annotations and preprocessing.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to find a 41 x 41 square that only contains black (value 0).

You can achieve that by performing a 41 x 41 dilation and choosing any black pixel, which is the center of the desired square. (Image binarized for clarity; the white squares are due to spurious pixels in the original image.)

[image]